# how to sum two column within single case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query below returns 2 rows, but actually I need only one;

```
select Datename(month, m.CreatedDate) as [Ay], sum(case when h.Cinsiyet=1 then 1 else 0 end) as [Group1], sum(case when h.Cinsiyet=2 then 1 else 0 end) as [Group2] from Muayene.Muayene m with(nolock)
join Ortak.Hasta h with(nolock) on m.HastaTc = h.HastaTc
group by  h.Cinsiyet, Datename(month, m.CreatedDate)
```

result:

```
MonthName Group1 Group2
April     4500   0
April     0      9000
```

Expected Result:

```
MonthName Group1 Group2
April     4500   9000
```

I know I can do it wrapping the query with another select statement and Group by month and Sum these results.. But its not efficient and looks dirty code.

How can I make a trick to get expected result without make another sum statement?

Comment: The syntax suggests SQL Server so I added the tag.

Answer (score 1):

FIx the `GROUP BY`:

```
select Datename(month, m.CreatedDate) as [Ay],
       sum(case when h.Cinsiyet = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [Group1],
       sum(case when h.Cinsiyet = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as [Group2]
from Muayene.Muayene m join
     Ortak.Hasta h 
     on m.HastaTc = h.HastaTc
group by Datename(month, m.CreatedDate);
```